# Community Page Graph Picture Requires User Access Token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

Starting last month, it appears that community pages either require a user access token to access the graph image, or will not allow application to access the image.

As an example: The community page for Harold and Maude (105636526135846), last month would return a picture -- now calls to the graph do not include the picture string.

> {
>
> > "id": "105636526135846",
> >       "name": "Harold and Maude",
> >       "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Harold-and-Maude/105636526135846",
> >       "likes": 143886,
> >       "category": "Movie",
> >       "is_community_page": true,
> >     ...

At one point it appeared that using an access token would work, however, now requesting '/105636526135846/picture' returns no picture and Facebook's embedded image is

> > http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBKNDbD3RCI0MXv&w=180&h=540&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2Fc%2Fc4%2FHarold_and_maude.jpg&fallback=hub_movie

Alternatively FQL appears to return the proper information

```
>[
>>  {
>>>    "pic": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA4PX9DD7wlHZmC&w=100&h=300&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2Fc%2Fc4%2FHarold_and_maude.jpg&fallback=hub_movie",<br />
>>>    "pic_large": "http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBKNDbD3RCI0MXv&w=180&h=540&url=http%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2Fc%2Fc4%2FHarold_and_maude.jpg&fallback=hub_movie"<br />
>> }<br />
>]
```

Is there something I'm missing with the graph? I'm concerned that the FQL method may stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia have started blocking certain images, based on their licensing. So Facebook runs it through a filter (safe_image.php) to check if it is allowed or not. If not, you get a default image. So using FQL will 'sometimes' return you a usable image, but the graph no longer will.

I have no idea if Facebook plan to continue offering the FQL call. Sorry!